# Android status bar show in Unty

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, screen

I'm triyng to show the status bar in an Android phone using Unity. I have try this code:

```
  void Start()   {

     this.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

     }
```

But an error appear;

```
Assets/Scenes/Control/control.cs(15,34): error CS0103: The name 'WindowManager' does not exist in the current context
```

Does I need to call or import another package? Some could help me with this detail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use native plugins https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html

Comment: You can also try to integrate this https://github.com/Over17/UnityShowAndroidStatusBar

Comment: Thanks it works the plugin!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use Android Java functions directly in Unity. You can only use whats available in Unity C Sharp. Unity doesn’t understand the method. Suggested workaround, use a ‘Slider’ UI element and manipulate it in a custom c sharp script. Complicated workaround create a custom Unity Plugin which calls the native Android method (possible but complex).

Comment: And there is a possibility to call an outside java function with Unity?